# Change minimum value of dojo slider from html select menu using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dojo, slider

I would like to change the minimum value of dojo slider using a html select menu. I tried using onchange function but I had some problem.
This is my starting code.

```js
require(["dojox/form/HorizontalRangeSlider", "dojo/dom", "dojo/domReady!"], function(HorizontalRangeSlider, dojoDom){
  
  var rangeSlider = new HorizontalRangeSlider({
    name: "rangeSlider",
    value: [2,6],
    minimum: -10,
    maximum: 10,
    intermediateChanges: true,
    style: "width:300px;",
    onChange: function(value){
      dojoDom.byId("sliderValueMin").value = value[0];
      dojoDom.byId("sliderValueMax").value = value[1];
    }
  }, "rangeSlider");
  
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.11.2/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.11.2/dojox/form/resources/RangeSlider.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.11.2/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <select id="zoneQuake" name="zoneQuake">
  <option value="1" id="one" name="one">One</span></option>
  <option value="2" id="two" name="two">Two</span></option>
 </select>


<div class="claro">
    <div id="rangeSlider"></div>
    <p><input type="text" id="sliderValueMin" /></p>
    <p><input type="text" id="sliderValueMax" /></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is the code, you have tried to update the slider value?
Also there is unwanted "" tags.

Here's how you can do it.

```js
require(["dojox/form/HorizontalRangeSlider", "dojo/dom", "dojo/on", "dijit/registry", "dijit/form/Select", "dojo/domReady!"], function(HorizontalRangeSlider, dojoDom, on,  registry){

  var zoneQuakeNode = dojoDom.byId("zoneQuake");
  on(zoneQuakeNode, "change", function(evt){
    var max = rangeSlider.value[1];
    rangeSlider.set("value", [evt.target.value, max]);
  });
  
  var rangeSlider = new HorizontalRangeSlider({
    name: "rangeSlider",
    value: [2,6],
    minimum: -10,
    maximum: 10,
    intermediateChanges: true,
    style: "width:300px;",
    onChange: function(value){
      dojoDom.byId("sliderValueMin").value = value[0];
      dojoDom.byId("sliderValueMax").value = value[1];
    }
  }, "rangeSlider");
  
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.11.2/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.11.2/dojox/form/resources/RangeSlider.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.11.2/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <select id="zoneQuake" name="zoneQuake" >
  <option value="1" id="one" name="one">One</option>
  <option value="2" id="two" name="two">Two</option>
 </select>


<div class="claro">
    <div id="rangeSlider"></div>
    <p><input type="text" id="sliderValueMin" /></p>
    <p><input type="text" id="sliderValueMax" /></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't want to update the slider value, I want to update the minimum value of the slider from -10 to 1 or 2.

Comment: Update the `minimum` instead of `value` That should update the slider minimum. `rangeSlider.set("minimum", evt.target.value);`

Comment: Ok, this is what I need. Thanks!